# how iterate over Object arrays with java reflection

Tags: java, reflection

I want to iterate over `Object[]` within a class with Reflection

this is my class :

```
public class Lab  {
    public Browser[] browser;
}

class Browser {
    String url;
}
```

I want to reach browser[] from the Lab class at index 3 and check value of url

Comment: Can you elaborate on what do you aim to do and what have you tried ? Isn't there another, simpler way than reflection ?

Comment: `myLabInstance.browser[3].url.equals("myValue")`?

Comment: my purpose it to reach it with reflection , im just testing my reflection skils and i found that i cant catch this case

Comment: Then I suggest you try it out yourself in a sandbox project, read the javadoc and discover for yourself what's available to you!

Comment: Perfect answer : "try it for yourself" . i m already dit it , but can't found

Comment: I get your point. But if your goal is purely to test your skills, then you'll learn so much more if you struggle to find the answer yourself. That said, what you need is https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#get-java.lang.Object- with a proper cast.

Comment: `browser` is *field* in `Lab` class. So first step is to "get value of field". When you already have value you can "test if it is array". When you know it is array "*access* value at specified *index* in array". Which of these steps you have problem with?

Comment: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/fields.html, http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/arrays.html, [Unpacking an Array using reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8095016)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that with something like the following snippet:

```
public boolean urlEquals(Lab lab, String other){
    try{
        Field browsersField = Lab.class.getDeclaredField("browsers");
        Object browsers = browsersField.get(lab);

        Object browser = Array.get(browsers, 3);

        Field urlField = Browser.class.getDeclaredField("url");
        urlField.setAccessible(true);
        Object url = urlField.get(browser);

        return url.equals(other);
    } catch(Exception e){ // probably catch specific exceptions than all
        throw new IllegalStateException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: i lab.browser[3] its not replection , i try to get full reflection . to reach url from the lab after it reach browser and url

Comment: `browswers[3]` doesn't use reflection. I am guessing OP wants something like `Array.get(someArray, index)`. Java provides `java.lang.reflect.Array` for that purpose.

Comment: @Pshemo thanks for that Input, I've edited it into my answer

Comment: BTW `equals` method accept `Object` type parameter so there is no need to cast `url` to String.

Comment: Thank you , @Lino . using you solution i fixed my problem , i will put here my solution later

Comment: @RomanGlaz You're welcome. Note that there is no need to put your solution on here, it will almost always be enough to *accept* the answer which helped the most. Because for future readers of your question a general answer may help more than a specific solution which works exactly for your case

Comment: @Lino how can i accept your solution ? , im a rookie here

Answer (score 0):

Maybe in this way:

```
public class Lab
{
public Browser[] browser;
public static void main(String[] args)
{
Lab myLabInstance = new Lab();
myLabInstance.browser = new Browser[] { new Browser(), new Browser(), new Browser(), new Browser(), };
for (Field field : Lab.class.getDeclaredFields())
{
  System.out.println(field.getName());
  if (field.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("browser"))
  {
    field.setAccessible(true);
    Browser[] browsers = (Browser[]) field.get(myLabInstance);
    System.out.println(browsers[3].url.equals("myvalue"));
  }
}}}

class Browser
{
 public String url = "hallo";
}
```

Comment: I think OP meant the other way around, `browsers` is available but `url` isn't

Comment: You can't convert Lab to brower[]

Comment: field.get(myLabInstance) returns Browser[] .. I have added the complete code to my postings, which works

Comment: what is myLabInstance ? LAB ? Browser ? Where you took it from ?

Comment: What is the type of myLABinstance? Is that a rhetorical question? ;-)

Comment: Why `field.setAccessible(true);` on `public` field? And why loop if we already know name of the field?

Comment: You are right, it's clear that both of them are not necessary for that case. But it demonstrates some additional features of reflection.